# Runtime analysis (C) Big-oh notation

Tags: c, data-structures, runtime, big-o

Consider a function whose body is:

```
sum = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= f(n); i++)
    sum += i;
```

where f(n) is a function call. Give a simple and tight big-oh upper bound on the running time of this function, as a function of n on the assumption that:

```
a) The running time of f(n) is O(n), and the value of f(n) is n!
b) The running time of f(n) is O(n), and the value of f(n) is n
c) The running time of f(n) is O(n²), and the value of f(n) is n
d) The running time of f(n) is O(1), and the value of f(n) is 0
```

I just want to make sure I am on the right track. My answers:

```
a) O(n²) 
b) O(n²)
c) O(n³)
d) O(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is not correct: f(n) has a value of n!, which is a [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). It grows very fast. The answer there should be O(n×n!), because you are calling a function with running time O(n) a total of n! times. I'm not sure if that can be simplified.

The others look fine.

Comment: Oh okay thanks... I thought because it went from i < n! it still ran in linear time. O(nxn!) isn't tight. Wouldn't it just be O(n)?

Comment: O(n) is a lot smaller. Why do you say that O(n×n!) isn't tight?

Comment: I was under the impression that tight had to be O(n), O(1), O(n²), etc...